# Perform segue click button from collection view inside table view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, delegates, tableview

I have a table view with a collection view in my 2nd cell. And I have a button in collection view cell.

When a button from the collection view is clicked, i want to perform a segue to another view controller. And pass data. (But only button, not cell)

Comment: you have to write protocol for button in collectionviewcell

Comment: is your collectionView inside tableView

Comment: can you write sample code ?

Comment: yes my collectionView inside my tableView

Comment: then you need to call your collectionViewdelegate methods in tableViewcell and you need to perform action on it

Comment: I need a sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` with data inside so you can add action for your button to your cell

```
class YourCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    var item: Item?
    ...
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    ...
}
```

now create delegate of your cell

```
protocol YourCellDelegate {
    func buttonPressed(pass data: Item)
}
```

and create variable of delegate in your cell

```
class YourCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    var delegate: YourCellDelegate?
    ...
}
```

then in button action call delegate method and pass data if you need to

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.buttonPressed(pass: item!)
}
```

Now implement `YourCellDelegate` protocol to your `UITableViewCell` and also declare what should happen when button is pressed. To achieve this, create delegate of your `UITableViewCell` and

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
    func buttonInYourCellPressed(pass data: Item)

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, YourCellDelegate {
    ...
    var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?
    ...
    func buttonPressed(pass data: Item) {
        delegate?.buttonInYourCellPressed(pass data: date)
    }
}
```

also in collection view data source method inside `UITableViewCell` set delegate of cell as your TableViewCell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    ...
    cell.delegate = self
    ...
}
```

finally implement your `TableViewCellDelegate` to your `UIViewController` and declare what should happen when button in collection view is pressed

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, TableViewCellDelegate {
    ...
    func buttonInYourCellPressed(pass data: Item) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifier", sender: data)
    }
}
```

At the end, set delegate of TableViewCell in `UITableView` data source method `cellForRowAt` as your ViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    cell.delegate = self
    ...
}
```

then in `prepare(for segue:` in your ViewController you can just assign property of destination ViewController to downcasted sender

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        destinationVC.selectedItem = sender as! Item
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working thx. But how can I get data from that cell and when perform segue how to display on another screen.

Comment: I want to ask you more. What if I pass two more data with this button, how can I add one or more value in sender ??

Comment: I used class for that but if you have better idea I'd like to know that.

Comment: @KaiTadashi you can’t pass more senders, but you can pass different data model, array, dictionary, ...

Comment: @KaiTadashi  that means, you can pass for example array of two objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have created cells in storyboard itself, then you can directly create @IBAction func in your main ViewController**

**OR**

**If you have created xib, then try this way**

You can do it in many ways, but i prefer doing it from Notification.

Try this

First of all you have to add an observer in your main controller from where you want to perform segue. just like this one :

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.testFunc(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("navigateToController"), object: nil)
```

Here is the code for your main class :

```
class YourMainViewController : UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var tableView : UITableView!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad()
          NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.testFunc(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("navigateToController"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func testFunc(notification:Notification)  {
         let object = notification.object as! YourObjectType /// For ex : [String], Int, CustomModel, Any etc..
         let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
         let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewController") as! YourViewController
         viewController.object = object
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is the code for your table view cell class :

```
class yourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCollectionCell
            cell.yourCellButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.actionCellButton()), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cell
      }

     @objc func actionCellButton() {
         let myArr = ["1","2","3"]
         NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("navigateToController"), object: myArr)
     }
}
```

When you will click your button, **actionCellButton()** function will be called and from here you can pass data into notification object.

Just after the **actionCellButton()** function is called, **testFunc()** will be called and there you will receive your data which you passed in **actionCellButton()** function and code will be executed.